# Only two social profile links listed in the Knowledge Graph

Tags: google-search, schema.org, social-media, knowledge-graph

We have a local business listing (and a G+ page) for our website. We have Structured Data configured to list our social profiles :

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "url": "https://www.bidpress.com",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/bidPress",
    "https://instagram.com/bidpress",
    "https://www.twitter.com/bidpress",
    "https://plus.google.com/+bidPress"
  ],
  "name": "bidPress",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "New York",
    "addressRegion": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10014",
    "streetAddress": "659 Washington Street, Suite 5R"
  },
  "email": "mailto:help@bidpress.com",
  "telephone": "+1 (888) 463-5823",
  "legalName": "bidPress",
  "logo": "https://www.bidpress.com/t-shirt-design-bidpress-logo.png"
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "name": "bidPress",
  "url": "https://www.bidpress.com",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/bidPress",
    "https://instagram.com/bidpress",
    "https://www.twitter.com/bidpress",
    "https://plus.google.com/+bidPress"
  ]
}
</script>
```

Only Twitter and Facebook show up, the other two don't. How can I get the other two to show up?

[image: Screenshot of Google search, showing the social profiles 'Twitter' and 'Facebook']

Comment: Working as intended... Google doesn't require SameAs to associate social media profiles, since had the ability to detect profiles long before Schema came into effect. Schema, doesn't always mean additional information will be returned in the search results, this is explained by Google. Furthermore you need to ensure you are active on those social platforms.

Comment: Similar issue (also only 2 social profiles get displayed): [*Correct way to use sameAs itemprop in Microdata*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/98489/17633)

Comment: Why do you repeat much of the `LocalBusiness` information in a separate `Organization` node?

Answer (score 1):

A quick testing of your structured data will give you any errors.
[Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/)

All though Google recommends JSON. Their example for social is as follows.

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.your-company-site.com">
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.facebook.com/your-company">FB</a>
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.twitter.com/YourCompany">Twitter</a>
</span>
```

**EDIT:** Couple of more things to consider. If it is less than one week, wait it out till the end of the week. Google suggests to contact them if they all do not work after 1 week and the markup has been tested and passed, which your site has.

More importantly, your profiles have to be verified. 
You can learn how to properly verify all social accounts here [How To Verify Your Social Media Profiles](https://www.quintly.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-verify-your-social-media-profiles/)